# In Django is there a way to aggregate over relationships with a condition on the related object

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

The Django aggregation documentation give this example that counts the number of `Book`s related to each `Publisher` and returns a query set with the top 5 publishers annotated with thier book count (like appending a new field with this count):

```
>>> pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book')).order_by('-num_books')[:5]
>>> pubs[0].num_books
1323
```

But I need to count only a specific type of book. Something like.

```
>>> pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book__type="nonfiction"')).order_by('-num_books')[:5]
```

Is there a filter I can use to accomplish this or do I need to resort to raw SQL?

The above is the docs example analogous to my real problem which is to identify and quantify the biggest medical groups by the number of hospitals in their system, when systems and hospitals are both modeled as healthcare `Entity`s:

```
>>> biggest_systems = Entity.objects.filter(relationships__type_id=NAME_TO_TYPE_ID.get('hospital')).annotate(num_hospitals=Count('relationships')).order_by('-num_hospitals')[:5]
>>> biggest_systems[0].num_hospitals
25
```

`relationships` is an Entity M2M field with a through table, type_id is a field within Entity as well:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID',primary_key=True, db_column='ID') 
    type_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='detailed type',db_column='TypeID', blank=True, editable=True, choices=ENTITYTYPE_CHOICES, help_text="A category for this healthcare entity.")
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name='affiliated with', through='EntityRelationship', symmetrical=False, related_name='related_to+')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Order of annotate() and filter() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses):

```
Publisher.objects.filter(book__rating__gt=3.0).annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

Or in your case:

```
Publisher.objects.filter(book__type='nonfiction').annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

Comment: Wow. Can it be that simple? Checking it now.

Comment: Yep, I was impressed too, first I thought that this would filter publishers with at least a book of type 'nonfiction'. So I tried it (yes I actually tried it, I thought at least I'd come up with some ORM voodoo tricks ...) and it did filter the book type for the annotation ... Great question, good to know, upvoted the question B)

Comment: My num_books is coming out equal to 1 for all that make it through the filter, but my "real" example is bit more complicated--self-referencing M2M with through table with fields (attributes) in the `through` (relationship intermediary) table. Don't want to accept your answer till I'm doubly sure (by trying the docs example) that there isn't some Voodo that isn't producing what we expect.

Comment: Can you post your actual models and some data ? (./manage.py dumpdata yourapp.yourmodel1 yourapp.yourmodel2 etc ...) thanks !

Comment: Wilco. Just checked and you're right, it works perfectly, even form my more complicated example. If I could double upvote I would. My initial mistake was takeing the first few publishers in the list sorted in increasing instead of decreasing order. I was looking for the biggest nonfiction publishers not the smallest (per the docs example). Will post my real example, looking for the biggest medical groups by the number of hospitals in their system.

Comment: No need to bother with posting your actual code, accepting the answer is sufficient + thanks for the kind words, my pleasure to help !